# how to get current process ID and machine name in C++

Tags: c++

In C#, it is straightforward to get the current process ID and machine name:

```
int processID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
string machineName = Environment.MachineName;
```

How can I retrieve them in native C++?

Comment: You can't as this isn't part of the C++ standard, it depends on the operating system

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: Did C++11 get `boost::this_thread::get_id()`?

Comment: @Ulterior as opposed to C++/CLI

Comment: @Flexo it sure did. But that's not the process ID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you commented the platform is Windows 7, the WINAPI provides [GetCurrentProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetComputerName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Simple example for `GetComputerName()`:

```
const int BUF_SIZE = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;
char buf[BUF_SIZE] = "";
DWORD size = BUF_SIZE;

if (GetComputerNameA(buf, &size)) // Explicitly calling ANSI version.
{
    std::string computer_name(buf, size);
}
else
{
    // Handle failure.
}
```

Comment: I am not a C++ programmer, after I added this line DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentProcessId(void); in a header file, how can I get the ID then?

Comment: Add `#include <windows.h>` and just call the function: `DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();`

Comment: DWORD is a 32-bit `unsigned int`, so use `unsigned int`.

Comment: getCurrentProcessID() is fine. GetComputerName() is more complicated. could you tell me how to use it?

Comment: @devn, added example to answer.

Comment: I got an error: error C2664: 'GetComputerNameW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [16]' to 'LPWSTR'

Comment: then I need to convert wstring to string?

Comment: Or you can explicitly call `GetComputerNameA()` and use `char` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

`getpid()` && `gethostname()` - use `man` to learn all about them...

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the O/S? (I am being rhetorical, cos I know it does).

Comment: @nim i deleted my comment but i assume OP meant that he does not want to use functions which are not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @trojanfoe, have you seen: http://www.suacommunity.com/dictionary/getpid-entry.php ;)

Comment: @nim So all O/S have those functions?

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes I would expect so, but just to make things difficult, they will be called something slightly different... hence the usefulness of something like the site I linked above.

Comment: @devn, `man` is the help equivalent in the *nix world, kind of redundant comment given you are on windows... (btw. `gethostname` has an equivalent too, browse through the sight I linked above)

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
 return GetCurrentProcessId(); 
#else
 return ::getpid();
#endif
```